# How to fill through model instances using forms or formsets

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following models :

```
class criterion(models.Model):
    quantity = '0'
    quality = '1'
    ascending = '0'
    descending = '1'
    three = '3'
    five = '5'
    seven = '7'
    ten = '10'
    type_choices = (
        (quantity,'Ποσοτικό'),
        (quality,'Ποιοτικό'),
        )
    monotonicity_choices = (
        (ascending,'Αύξον'),
        (descending,'Φθίνον'),
        )
    a_choices = (
        (three,'Τριβάθμια'),
        (five,'Πενταβάθμια'),
        (seven,'Εφταβάθμια'),
        (ten,'Δεκαβάθμια'),
        )
    criterion_research = models.ForeignKey('research', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    criterion_name = models.CharField(max_length = 200,verbose_name='Όνομα Κριτηρίου')
    criterion_type = models.CharField(max_length = 15,choices = type_choices , default = quantity,verbose_name='Τύπος')
    criterion_monotonicity = models.CharField(max_length = 15,choices = monotonicity_choices , default = ascending,verbose_name='Μονοτονία')
    criterion_a = models.CharField(max_length = 30,choices = a_choices , default = five,verbose_name='Κλίμακα',help_text='Επιλέξτε μία από τις 4 κλίμακες που θα μετρηθεί το κριτήριο.')
    criterion_worst = models.FloatField(default=' ',verbose_name='Χειρότερη Τιμή',help_text='Επιλέξτε τη χειρότερη τιμή την οποία μπορεί να πάρει το κριτήριο.',blank=True)
    criterion_best = models.FloatField(default=' ',verbose_name='Καλύτερη Τιμή',help_text='Επιλέξτε τη καλύτερη τιμή την οποία μπορεί να πάρει το κριτήριο.',blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.criterion_name

class alternative(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200,verbose_name='Όνομα Εναλλακτικής')
    ranking = models.IntegerField(default='1')
    alternative_research = models.ForeignKey('research', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    criteria = models.ManyToManyField('criterion', through='criterionvalue',blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class criterionvalue(models.Model):
    value = models.IntegerField(default='0')
    alt = models.ForeignKey('alternative',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    crit = models.ForeignKey('criterion',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have made a view that populates the criterion instances and the alternative instances(except the manytomany field).

I want to query for all the possibles criterion and alternatives and then based on that populate the criterionvaue instances.After I complete these I want then to specify the manytomany relatioship of the criterionvalue instances with the alternatives instances .I thought of making a formset of criterionvalue model  then associate them(the forms made by the formset) with the  alternatives and criteria using the length of the alternatives and criteria queryset(In order to render the relatioship matrix using forms) .

But I think such an idea is farfetched.
Any ideas on how i could achieve such thing ?

Comment: Geia sou Thodori! Vasika rotas polla pragmata kai diskola tha sou apantisei kaneis. Prepei na gineis pio sigkekrimenos kai pio litos stis erotiseis sou. Filika Nikos!

Comment: Kalhspera Niko , to provlima pou exo einai oti thelo meso formon na gemizo ta instances tou modelou criterionvalue .To na paro ta data apo formes einai eukolo alla meta prepi na oriso kai ta foreignkeys .Pos tha kitao tautoxrona kai tis formes kai ta queryset apo ta alla dio modela oste na boune ola sosta kai na dhmiourgithi o pinakas alternative/criterion .